# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'post.profile_picture' )

Tags: javascript, react-native

so i have been getting this error a lot when working with arrays so i write an array in a seperated file but when i (export/import) and want to use it on another file (component )  it gives me this error , but if write the array inside the second file directly it works ??? i can keep REtyping that array but i want my code with no repetitions ! so what is the problem please
code :
*THE ARRAY FILE* :

```
const USERS =[
  {
      user: 'cleverqazi',
      image:'https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/kensingtonroyal-79486960-257028741946498-6632966373034557484-n-1593172690.jpg',
  },
  {
      user: 'hyrixlele',
      image :'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT227CvLOL-LPbvwX9G1Fr-SQsTTCdHiA-6Pw&usqp=CAU',
  },
  {
      user :'jackdone',
      image:'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQlceGeHkpTiNVSv8bna9crjKxvlS38_ka-tw&usqp=CAU',
  },
  {
      user:'donetravitoleaon',
      image:'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTdqteCJFZbpnYbaLhmdf9fv756Sc4PQJ6PfQ&usqp=CAU',
  },
  {
      user:'cristiano.ronaldo',
      image:'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQgDBFdFku800IEsJnhIB33SNN5UKZy2cnJaw&usqp=CAU',
  }
]
```

THE SECOND ONE :

```
       <ScrollView>
         {POSTS.map((post,index)=>(
             <Post post={post} key={index}/>
         ))}
       </ScrollView>
```

Comment: have you tried importing exporting? your array is USERS but you're mapping over POSTS

Comment: Yes bro i exported it because USERS are used IN POSTS i just didnt want to type it here because its too long ! but i did export it

Comment: Is that the correct array? Each `user` entity seems to have properties named `user` and `image`, so naturally trying to access `user.profile_picture` will be undefined. If it is correct, try using `post.image` instead in your component.

Comment: @ZakiKendil can you share the code where you export and import?

Comment: `import USERS from '../components/Home/Stories'
import { POSTS } from '../data/posts';



const   HomeScreen=()=>{
    return(
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Header/>
        <Stories/>
        <ScrollView>
          {POSTS.map((post,index)=>(
              <Post post={post} key={index}/>
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
    );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'black',

    },
  });
export default HomeScreen;`

Comment: and this one is on the post component  `<View>
                <Image source={{uri:post.profile_picture}} style={styles.story}/>
                <Text style={styles.ProfileName}>{post.user}</Text>
            </View>`